# AWK command to display Header, Transform and Footer?

Tags: awk

I have used the below command,

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Header"};{FIELDWIDTHS ="3 4 3"}{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"
|"};END{print "Footer"}' file8
```

Actual -

```
Header
1234567890|||
234|5678|901|
345|6789|012|
098|7654|321|
Footer
```

Expectation -

```
Header
123|4567|890|
234|5678|901|
345|6789|012|
098|7654|321|
Footer
```

Comment: we miss a bit of information there. What's the content of file8 ?

Comment: You need to move the `FIELDWIDTHS` assignment into the `BEGIN` block

Comment: File8 is, 1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
9876543210

Comment: I tried with, awk 'BEGIN{print "Header"};BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS ="3 4 3"}{print $1"|"$2"
|"$3"|"};END{print "Footer"}' file8      --It is displaying as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is coming out wrong because the action `{FIELDWIDTHS ="3 4 3"}` doesn't get applied until after the first line has been read and parsed.

If you move the `FIELDWIDTHS` definition inside the `BEGIN` block it will work as intended:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Header"; FIELDWIDTHS ="3 4 3"}{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"};END{print "Footer"}' file8
```

Note that `FIELDWIDTHS` might only be supported in GNU Awk (`gawk`).

Answer (score 0):

Achieved by below command and it worked fine too

command:

```
awk 'NR==1{$0=substr($1,1,3)"|"substr($1,4,3)"|"substr($1,6,3)"|"}1'    filename
```

output

```
 awk 'NR==1{$0=substr($1,1,3)"|"substr($1,4,3)"|"substr($1,6,3)"|"}1' l.txt 
123|456|678|
234|5678|901|
345|6789|012|
098|7654|321|
Footer
```