# awk command to add header, footer along with fixed length file

Tags: awk

I could convert delimited file to fixed length file with the below command:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1$2$3}' file9
```

But i would also like to add Header and Footer in addition

File9 -

```
123|4567|890|
```

Expectation -

```
Header
1234567890
Footer
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some input lines and the expected output.

Comment: Unless the first 3 columns are all the same width, your command doesn't seem to to what you want at all.  It's basically just removing `|`

Comment: Possible duplicate of your previous question [AWK command to display Header, Transform and Footer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516685/awk-command-to-display-header-transform-and-footer)

Comment: @αғsнιη it seems to me to be a variation of the previous question; that one is specifically inserting delimiters, this one is removing them.

Comment: @JeffSchaller In OP's previous question xe already knows how to add header&footer as shown in the command xe come with it, doesn't xe? as well as showed in recived answers there. so I believe this new question here is useless extra question by him/her. However question is not asking to removing delimiter, it's asked how to add header & footer apart of question's title .

Comment: It is a bit confusing, since the question's title doesn't mention removing the delimiter, yet the code and expected output *do* remove it. I'll refrain from voting, in case it's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a header or a footer in awk can be done with a BEGIN and an END block:

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN {print "header"}
    {print $1$2$3}
    END { print "footer" }' file9
```

I don't really see how `print $1$2$3` converts your file to a "fixed length file", but this will give you the header and footer.

Comment: I have also checked working with, awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {print "header"}
    {print $1$2$3}
    END { print "footer" }' file9